# How to find the relative path to my javascript in node/express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node/express app with:

```
.set('views', __dirname + '/dist')
```

`dist` has a subdirectory `guestApp`.

in `dist/guestApp` I have an html page `guest.html` and a JavaScript file: `vendor.js`.

The html page has a script tag with: `src='vendor.js'`

I render the page with: `response.render('guestApp/guest.html', {activeProfile: 'Me', title: 'World'});`

The page is rendered, but the JavaScript is not found. I have tried all sorts of combinations but I can't seem to get it right. What is the correct relative path to that script please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your html file is not dynamic you don't need to set views. You have to setup the static middleware.

`app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/dist'));`

And the javascript file should also be referenced relative to the dist directory -

`src='guestApp/vendor.js'`

Comment: My html is dynamic. I have edited the post for correctness. I changed the script tag: src="dist/guestApp/vendor.js", but still get a 404.

Comment: That is ok. Your javascript files are static files, so you have to setup the static middleware. if your have set your static middleware pointing to dist directory, change src to `guestApp/vendor.js`. Just beware of position of the static middleware. Add it after the `set('view'...` thing